# How to decode a sqlite3 format file(binary) resource in php

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm working on a web solution that allows user to view an online sqlite3 format file (e.g. http://xxxxxx.AgentStatistic.csv.sqlite3). Now I'm using php, and successfully get the resource with codes:

```
$url ="http://xxxxx.AgentStatistic.csv.sqlite3";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This returns the binary code, which can be viewed like this, a long string (with unreadable code):

```
SQLite format 3@  -â!     iiƒSS…tableLitevsocial_reports_agentStatisticsLitevsocial_reports_agentStatisticsCREATE TABLE Litevsocial_reports_agentStatistics (reportTime,conversationId,dayPeriod,weekPeriod,monthPeriod,yearPeriod,agent,groupUser,dayLogin,weekLogin,monthLogin,yearLogin,assignedTo,assignedBy,composePublish,composeDraft,replyPublish,replyDraft,closed,waitingTime,slaReply,slaReplyOutside,slaClosed,slaClosedOutside)       Î ûöñìçâÝØÓÎ\S J A8/& /˜7Öu³Rñ/_ 3 +2013-06-03 17:43:3972579thisYearChris 00002000000112080160001_   3 +
.....(all rows with unreadable code like the first line)
```

The result includes the information I needed but is not readable and in bad format.
My question: is there a method to properly decode the sqlite3 resource based on my existing code? Or there are some other solutions in other language?

Comment: Why don't you write it to a file and tell the SQLite library to open it?

Comment: what format of the file do you mean (I guess it's .db, but I don't know how to do it)? Which SQLite library? I could not find a library that can deal with .sqlite3. I'd appreciate if you can name it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Comment: Yeap. It does solve my problem. Thanks CL!